# Use existing Hashset as Keys to create new dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashset

If i have an existing Hashset of type T, how would i create a dictionary out of it like;

```
Dictionary<T, object> tmp = new Dictionary<T, object>();
```

This can be done using the following code

```
Hashset<string> hashset = new Hashset<string>()

foreach(var key in hashset)
    tmp[key] = null;
```

Is there an easier way of doing this, rather than having a loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, by using the [overload of the `Enumerable.ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548657%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method that has both a key selector and a value selector parameter.

```
var dictionary = hashset.ToDictionary(h => h , h => (object)null);
```

because you're selecting `null` for the value, it's necessary to ensure it's a null `object` (`null` needs to be specified with a type), hence the cast.

Comment: null doesnt have type. Its more appropriate to say: "null should be specified with a type". +1